# UIBarButton Rendering Issues

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Currently, I am implementing somewhat of a custom UIBarButtonItem when I use a couple custom methods to change the positioning of the button image to move it to the right of the text and add some padding. However, when I leave the screen and come back the buttons text and images get switched and distorted as can be seen in the attached images.

[image]

[image]

First picture is the way the button looks when i leave the screen and come back second picture is what it originally looks like. i have included the code for the uibarbuttonitem if anyone sees anything I don't that is causing this rendering issue I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LocationManager: UIBarButtonItem {
    var viewController: MainViewController?

    lazy var customButton : UIButton = {
        let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        customButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "downArrow"), for: .normal)
        customButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, -10)
        guard let customFont = UIFont(name: "NoirPro-SemiBold", size: 20) else {
            fatalError("""
        Failed to load the "CustomFont-Light" font.
        Make sure the font file is included in the project and the font name is spelled correctly.
        """
            )
        }
        customButton.semanticContentAttribute = UIApplication.shared
            .userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? .forceLeftToRight : .forceRightToLeft
        customButton.titleLabel?.font = customFont
        customButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        return customButton
    }()



    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupViews()
    }

    @objc func setupViews(){
        customView = customButton

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`customView` should be of type `UIView`. I suspect using the higher type of `UIButton` is causing issues. Within your `customView` you will need to set up the title and image as sub views and constrain according to your wishes.

Comment: trying this now